# Styling tag related to an input with webkit-autofill pseudoclass

Tags: html, css, autocomplete, webkit, stylesheet

I'm trying to style a sibling related to an input with the -webkit-autofill pseudoclass like this:

```
input:-webkit-autofill~span.add-on { background-color: #FAFFBD;}
```

But it doesn't work. Is it posible to achieve what I'm trying? Or should I rely on javascript for this?

Updated with HTML:

```
<div>
  <span class="add-on icon-user"></span
  <input type="text" id="user_name" name="user[user_name]">
</div>
```

To clear up things, what I want to achieve is to set the same background color for the span element when the input is autofilled.

Comment: I am assuming using a class isn't an option. Also could we see your HTML?

Comment: No, a class is not possible since that pseudoclass is added by webkit when it autocompletes a form. I will update with the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You can't style a preceding sibling with pure CSS. The selector `~` matches a sibling that comes after the first element.

Or as one could read it in the MDN docs:

> The ~ combinator separates two selectors and matches the second element only if it is preceded by the first, and both share a common parent.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/General_sibling_selectors

```
input:-webkit-autofill~span.add-on { background-color: #FAFFBD;}
```

would match the span in:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id="user_name" name="user[user_name]">
    <span class="add-on icon-user"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought ~ would match any sibling of the first selector that match the second, but it seems I was wrong. So... the only way to achieve what I'm trying is with js, right?